# Turning on LEDs

Tags: microcontroller, led, 555

I started a small project where I want to have three LEDs which are turning on gradually (in first step just one is on, one second step two are shining and then all three).

I've tried doing it via microcontrollers but isn't here any simlplier way, for instance with NE555?

---

Thanks everyone for their answers. I'll try figure it out throught MCU and hope thant nothing will go wrong.

Comment: Microcontroller is the way to go. Very few components and once you get them to light the rest is programming, very predictable and can be modified without solder.

Comment: Do you mean "simpler" as in fewer external components, or "simpler" as in fewer transistors *inside* the components?  If you mean "simpler to design and manufacture" then use a microcontroller, as @Transistor suggests.  One itty bitty PIC or Atmel ATTiny, some lines of assembly (or PICBasic), or one Arduino Nano or whatever is super-teeny, and you're done.  If you mean three to six 1970's-era chips on a board, then let us know.

Comment: Jirka, when I'm teaching MCU programming to a class of students, the first lesson plan steps are on the topic of driving LEDs. The first 15 lesson steps are ***only*** on driving LEDs. No input, yet. This takes a student from just getting their code to run and turn on an LED to driving an LED through a series of geometric duty cycle changes which lead to the appearance of a gradual increase and gradual decrease in intensity. But this last lesson, they've learned a lot; including details about how humans perceive brightness. Driving multiple LEDs is an easy 16th step. But I move on to input.

Comment: @jonk makes a good point - your eye's perception of LED "brightness" isn't linear. Yes, you can add circuits to a 555 to achieve an apparent gradual increase of light, but it is a *lot easier* to adapt microcontroller code to do the same.

Comment: **WHY** has ANYONE close voted this? What's the mindset? Comment useful.

Comment: When you say "gradually" do you mean that each LED grows in brightness with time? - or do they "snap on" in order? What sort of delays are wanted?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon because you know this site hates anyone that doesn't have 3 PHDs.

Comment: @Passerby I've been known to tell my wife (not for some time now) that I've earned 3 PhDs by now - BUT, I haven't been awarded one :-). Lots of fun along the way. ME (EE) is as close as I'll get in this lifetime :-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want oldskool analog:

First, a ramp/sawtooth generator, which you can build with an opamp, or a comparator, or a 555. If you want to have it do only one run at power-up, a resistor charging a capacitor will make a voltage ramp too.

Then a vu-meter circuit like LM3914 turns your voltage ramp into a bunch of LEDs lighting one after the other.

If you want the LEDs to turn on gradually in turn, not just on/off, you can do that by adding another sawtooth/triangle on top of your ramp.

Here's a big sawtooth plus a small sawtooth, and the output of 3 comparators with spaced thresholds driving 3 LEDs...

[image]

These days, it's simpler with a micro.

**EDIT: More analog.**

Big capacitors are expensive, so I'll use only one. Power supply goes from 0V to 5V at t=0.

[image]

For simpler inventory management, let's get rid of the diodes. 12V version.

[image]

Less parts. BJTs going into saturation trigger the next LED. 5V supply.

[image]

Comment: Don't forget human perception is log. So the duty cycle changes vs time aren't linear, but non-linear. Part of my lesson plan is to start the student doing the changes based upon a linear change in duty cycle. Then later to do it right. It's very easy to see the difference between those two methods and all students will prefer the appearance of the non-linear change method when they get to see it for themselves.

Comment: @jonk Yes! Log is much better, especially for dimming.

Comment: I have the students do both. The LED is dimmed and then brightened, in an ever-repeating cycle. The dimming must appear to the human eye to be linear in both directions. The geometric approach in ramping up is the symmetric complement to ramping down. Works very nice.

Comment: So an oldskool analog implementation of this would look much better with incandescent lights, as these have a nonlinear PWM to light output curve...

Comment: Well, there's some slight problems with that idea. One, incandescent lights don't come pre-installed on a [TI EZ430-F2013](https://www.ti.com/tool/EZ430-F2013) and would be cumbersome to add, if not impossible. Two, it would defeat the whole purpose of learning to use LEDs and timers in sophisticated ways to achieve a result. Three, it would make me have to explain incandescent lights behaviors, which are complex, and rather than motivating them to learn about timers it would instead distract them away from very important programming lessons into minutiae about which they don't need to know.

Comment: Sure! I was only suggesting incandescents for a solution without microcontroller.

Comment: Which would defeat my class, entirely! But yes, I get that.

Comment: Enough work in here I have to +1. But egads.

Comment: @jonk Hey I learned a new English expression "egad"! So I've added some analog schematics with log ramp...

Comment: I'd +1 you again if I could. Great to learn new English. My German is only updated when I occasionally read web sites and newspaper articles there. I wish I could get more practice. But I live in an isolated, provincial country far far away. ;)

Comment: Evilly marvellous. MArvellously evil. | I had been thinking of diode shaping - some problems with LED load if unbuffered. With buffers ! :-) | Your triple Darlington may (!) have several parallel factors at work. High current gain favours Q3. But 1st currents in Q1 occur while Vbe Q2 Q3 are very low, so ... . Would be interesting. || Emitter followers in place of diode in interstage couplings change the rules too.

Comment: 3rd schematic is more evil, it lights the leds in right to left order.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps feed the input of a LM3915 from a slowly charging capacitor

Answer (score 1):

Two simple examples.
Neither anywhere as easy or flaxible or capable as a microcontroller solution.
The time spent learning to make an Arduino flash an LED will repay itself many many many times over.

In fig 1 LEDs light as the capacitors charge.
Charge time constants are C1R1, C2R2, C3R3.
Delays here are in the order of seconds.
Capacitor values are undesirably large.

In fig2 the opamp buffers the resistor-capacitor time delay so the R can be larger and the C smaller.
This shows one stage. Repeat as desired.
R5C4 time constant is 1 second -  so depending on V+ the LED will start to light in around one second and the grow brighter over several seconds.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq3iGC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Had to +1 this. The OP really needs to program, though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly opinion-based on whether discrete hardware logic is easier than coding, but a single 555 timer and a few components is not able to fade multiple LEDs individually off to on. Off the top of my head, you can use a LM3914/5/6 with a 555 or other type of timer, or maybe a fun light IC or led driver IC that as a slow fade option. Or maybe pair it with a CD4017 decade counter with multiple stages of resistors, but that's not going to be a smooth fading, more like jumping from 30% to 60% to 100% on per led. It's doable but...

At that point, you are poring over IC data sheets and debugging hardware circuits to fine tune a specific application that you can code directly with a much smaller debug time. Or simply stealing/borrowing someone else's code. With USB programmable micro controllers so the only thing you need is the micro controller and some LEDs/resistors/transistors, the micro controller route is much easier. But again, that's an opinion.

Comment: I'm tempted to provide a solution case for the MSP430 (I use the [TI EZ430-F2013](https://www.ti.com/tool/EZ430-F2013)) for one LED and see if the OP can propagate that into more. But dumping code here probably isn't the way to answer the OP in this forum.